# Magento store view redirects not working in 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento, redirect, magento-1.8

I have a store I'm developing that has two store views, one for each language I'm supporting. The products and categories have localized url keys.

In 1.7.0.2 my language switcher would redirect correctly (for ones that had "Create Permanent Redirect" as well as ones with out) but after upgrading to 1.8.0.0, it did not work any more.

## Problem

There is a regression in 1.8.0.0, they updated Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front to use `::_getRequestRewriteController()` in `::dispatch()` previously it used Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite and now it uses Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request

On line 143 of app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite/Request.php it has `$stores = $this->_app->getStores();` which returns an array of store_id index stores, but it goes on to check if the store it goes on to check with $fromStore, which is a variable from the GET params, ___from_store, which contains the store views key (e.g. default, french, etc), obviously this has problems looking up using a alpha key in a numericly index array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The offending line is again, #143 in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite/Request.php, by simpling changing it to $stores = $this->_app->getStores(false, true) it will work, as the 2nd parameter being true (defaults to false) returns the array with store view codes as the array key.

Hope this helps someone, and if anyone knows the best way to pass this on to the Magento developers, I would appreciate it, as I said, the issue reporting just posted to the home page, which doesn't seem to work.

Edit: I would also like to point out as 1.8.1.0 this is still an issue.

Comment: Scheduled to be fixed in nearest version. Unofficial/not tested patch https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/8696196